# Laravel Error: The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given

Tags: php, exception, laravel

I am receiving the above error in following code and totally unable to find out real cause.

```
        if ($validation->fails()) {
            // if it fails...
            return Redirect::to("login")->withErrors($validation)->withInput();
        } else {
            // storing user session... if it passes...
            $username =  Input::get("username");
            Session::put("username", $username);
            return Redirect::to("/");
        }
```

Comment: `withInput()` or `Redirect::to("/")` is boolean. Check results before returning them.

Comment: Is this Laravel 4 or 5? Or 3?

Answer (score 0):

Check out filters.php, make sure thar Closure return null or no returns when it passes validation.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are authenticating users. Why not use [Laravel's authentication](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security) that is offered to you out of box?

For you code, not sure if it's the chained withInput() causing the error, anyway I am strongly against chaining withErrors and withInput, for it will be problematic. A better approach is to use

```
Input::flash();
```

See the [doc](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#old-input)